# Convert Procedural Approach into Set Based Approach in Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are using procedural approach (while loop) for inserting records into a  particular table. the insert syntax is like below,

```
DECLARE @CNT INT = 0,
@WEEK DATE = '2015-11-01',
@FLAG INT

CREATE TABLE #Tmpdata (officeId int,id smallint, weekDate date,startsOn varchar(10),endsOn varchar(10),flag bit);

WHILE (@CNT <7)
BEGIN
    SET @WEEK = DATEADD(D,@CNT,@WEEK )

    IF EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM YEARRANGE
    WHERE @WEEK BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,taxseasonbegin) 
    AND CONVERT (DATE,taxSeasonEnd)
    )
    BEGIN
      SET @FLAG =1 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
  SET @FLAG = 0
    END

   INSERT INTO #Tmpdata 
       (
       officeId,id,weekDate,startsOn,endsOn,flag
       )
   VALUES
       (
       5134,@lvCounter,@week,'09:00 AM','05:00 PM',@flag
       );

   SET @cnt=@cnt+1;
end
```

(NOTE : TaxSeason is from january to august).

Is it possible to re-write the above logic in `set based approach`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write this  as a set based approach, but there seem to be discrepancies in your code. 1. Your temp table is named differently while declaring and inserting. 2. Your counter is named differently in the while clause and when incrementing. 3. You are not doing anything with the @Flag. Please clarify

Comment: The value of @CNT seems not to Change. This should produce a endless loop.

Comment: @Adish , I have corrected the code now & I am using flag to set the season id (1 or 0)

Comment: @CPMunich , i have corrected the code now

Comment: The calculation of @week in the loop seems to be wrong. In the first loop you increment by 0(new value 0), then increment by 1(new value 1) then increment the incremented variable by 2 (new value 3), and so on ... Where does the value 2 go?

Comment: I was thinking of a solution similar to Sean's solution below. Please test it out and see if it serves your purpose.

Comment: It would be nice if the OP actually tried to figure things out before asking someone to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is making a number of assumption because you didn't post ddl or any consumable sample data. Also, there is a variable @lvCounter not defined in your code. This is perfect opportunity to use a tally or numbers table instead of a loop.

```
declare @lvCounter int = 42;

DECLARE @CNT INT = 0,
@WEEK DATE = '2015-11-01',
@FLAG INT;

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n))
    , cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1
    )

select 5134 as officeId
    , @lvCounter as Id
    , DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @WEEK) as weekDate
    , '09:00 AM' as startsOn
    , '05:00 PM' as EndOn
    , Flag
from cteTally t
cross apply 
(
    select CAST(count(*) as bit) as Flag
    from YearRange
    where DATEADD(Day, t.N, @WEEK) > CONVERT(DATE,taxseasonbegin) 
        AND DATEADD(Day, t.N, @WEEK) <= CONVERT (DATE,taxSeasonEnd)
) y
where t.N <= 7;
```

Comment: OP was using the incremented week value (SET @WEEK = DATEADD(D,@CNT,@WEEK )) to compare between 2 dates. You should modify your where clause in the sub query y accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please can you provide sample data?

You can do something like:

```
SELECT DateIncrement = SUM(DATEADD(D,@CNT,@WEEK)) OVER (ORDER BY officeID)
FROM...
```

This gets an incremented date value for each record which you can then check against your start and end dates.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some Kind of this one. This gives you the data I think you Need for your insert. I do not have a table named YEARRANGE so I couldn't test it completely

```
 DECLARE @CNT INT = 0, @WEEK DATE = '2015-11-01', @FLAG INT;

 CREATE TABLE #Tmpdata (officeId int,id smallint, weekDate date,startsOn varchar(10),endsOn varchar(10),flag bit);

 WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT  num AS cnt,
         DATEADD(D, SUM(num) OVER(ORDER BY num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            , @WEEK) AS [week]
 FROM
 (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY nl) -1 AS num
 FROM
 (SELECT NULL AS nl UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS nl UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS nl      UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS nl
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS nl  UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS nl  UNION ALL    SELECT NULL AS nl
 ) AS ni
 ) AS no
 )
 INSERT INTO #Tmpdata (officeId,id,weekDate,startsOn,endsOn,flag)
 SELECT 5134 AS officeID, cnt AS id, [week],'09:00 AM' AS startsOn,'05:00     PM' AS endsOn, COALESCE(A1.flag,0) AS flag
 FROM CTE
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT 1
              FROM YEARRANGE
              WHERE [week] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,taxseasonbegin) 
                           AND CONVERT (DATE,taxSeasonEnd)
             ) AS A1(flag);
```